# How to simplify this programme?

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, matrix

The main function is like the following code:

```
#f is a function that has two parameters and returns one value:
f <- function(a, b) {
   a * b
}

#x is a's value group
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
#y is b's value group
y <- c(4,5,6)
```

I want to get all the possible values of f(x, y), and the result should be a matrix to be clear. Now I am using the for loop:

```
m <- c(NULL)
for (a in x) {
   for (b in y) {
       m <- c(m, c(a, b))
    }
}
m <- matrix(m, 3, 4)
```

But it seems really very very silly.Can any one provide a simpler way?

Thank you.

Comment: Did my reply answer your question?

Comment: I think "outer" function is the simplest answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
outer(x, y, f)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    4    5    6
#[2,]    8   10   12
#[3,]   12   15   18
#[4,]   16   20   24
outer(y, x, f)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    4    8   12   16
#[2,]    5   10   15   20
#[3,]    6   12   18   24
```

Comment: @kanpu Glad to be of help. Please consider accept as the answer by clicking green tick mark.

Answer (score 3):

I guess `expand.grid` is what you are looking for.

```
getAllCombinations <- function(a,b,r=3,col = 4){
# this is the key
g <- expand.grid(a,b)
matrix(g$Var1*g$Var2,r,col)

}
# call the function
getAllCombinations(x,y)
```

EDIT: 
Gotta be a sportsman here. My own solution is actually the slowest by far, though it might be easier to understand than a lot of `lapply` and anonymous functions. If you'd benchmark it: @ExperimenteR does not only win the easy-to-read competition but also the race...

```
# performance
library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(
  outer(x, y, f),
  getAllCombinations(x,y),
  vrajs(),
  replications = 10000
 )
```

Note that, I turned @vrajs solution into a function to keep things fair.

Comment: Yes. I also think "outer" is a great function.

Answer (score 2):

I hope following will work for you

```
#x is a's value group
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
#y is b's value group
y <- c(4,5,6)

matrix(unlist(lapply(1:length(x), 
                     function(a){
                       lapply(1:length(y), 
                              function(b){x[a]*y[b]})})), 
              ncol = length(y), byrow = TRUE)


     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    8   10   12
[3,]   12   15   18
[4,]   16   20   24
```

Update: Explanation of Code

1. Outer lapply function run through index of x and call inner lapply
   for each element of x
2. Inner lapply function run through index of y and call function which will then return multiplication of index variable of x and y
3. unlist function unlist return list of lapply
4. matrix will create returned array according to dimension of y (as
   number of columns)

Comment: It work. lapply is better than for-loop. But I think the code is still not clean enough. And thank u anyway.

Comment: I have added logic as well. I hope now it is clear what is happening.

Comment: You are so kind. And thank you for your patient explaination.